# Send two different new order email to recipients based on product category woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to send two different email based on products in cart
Like suppose If i have A category product in cart then email should be sent to A recipient 
If i have B category product in cart then the mail should be sent to B recipient
If both the categories are in cart then email should be sent to both the recipients separately the order should be split into two emails.

Please help solved me this puzzle

Comment: Hi,
I want to split order into two emails if both the categories is in cart.